# Can access maven repository from behind proxy, need help

Tags: maven-2, proxy

I am trying to access maven repository from behind proxy.
I configured settings.xml correctly (i guess so...)

```
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>username</username>
      <password>password</password>  
      <host>12.34.56.78</host>
      <port>8080</port>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

But still I am getting an error message like... if i don't configure userid/password gets correct error message which is HTTP response code `407` - saying authentication required.
But If I configure correct/incorrect proxy authentication it always prints below error message....

```
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.2/maven-clean-plugin-2.2.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.2' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error trans
ferring file: Server redirected too many  times (20)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.2/maven-clean-plugin-2.2.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.2' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error trans
ferring file: Server redirected too many  times (20)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
```

Comment: Can you give a snippet of your settings.xml file how you configured the proxy, cause this sounds like not correct port/username/password etc.

Comment: <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>AP\daunddig</username>
      <password>P00nam-5</password>  
      <host>10.83.2.8</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <!--<nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>-->
    </proxy>

  </proxies>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it a NTLM proxy? If yes, try to supply `domainname\username` for the `username` (as suggested in [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@maven.apache.org/msg68676.html)).

```
<username>DOMAINNAME\USERNAME</username>
```

Comment: Yes I tried username with domain name and withouth domain name. but still it fails.

Comment: @DigambarDaund: can you run maven with -X to see if you get useful information?

Comment: @KhueVu it is obvious! you are changing proxy settings into the settings.xml file which you downloaded from site and you are running m2e which uses bundled maven so you have to go to preferences and change maven prefereces-> installations to point to your local maven installation which contains edited settings.xml by default Embedded is the value just change it!

Answer (score 38):

If above does not work

**Step #2: Add wagon-http-lightweight extension**

Wagon HTTP lightweight library allows us to overcome authentication limitations in Maven (3.0.4) when working with NTLM proxies. We can follow the steps below to add the Wagon HTTP lightweight library as a Maven extension:

- Download the `wagon-http-lightweight-2.2.jar` from [here](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-lightweight/2.2/wagon-http-lightweight-2.2.jar).
- Copy the `wagon-http-lightweight-2.2.jar` to `%M2_HOME%/lib/ext` folder.

**Example pom.xml to test the solution**

To test our approach, first create a simple Maven project with the following pom.xml:

```
<!-- pom.xml -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.thira.testmavenplugindl</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-maven-plugin-dl</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Test Maven Plugin Download Issue</name>
  <description>Example pom file to test Maven dependency download with NTLM proxies</description>
</project>
```

The run the Maven goal described below. This should execute successfully and download all Maven dependencies:

```
mvn clean install
```

Check your local repository directory (as defined in settings.xml file) to ensure all the dependencies are correctly downloaded.

Comment: Thank you, this is single solution which helped me to deal with NTLM!

Comment: though this posting is more than 3 years old, it save my day! thx.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033286/maven-proxy-settings-not-working/10625020#10625020 -- I think this basically describes the same solution, but without the need to manually download and copy files

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative is to get Cntlm (http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) on your machine, configure your NTLM proxy in cntlm.ini with your domain/password/proxy name etc.
run it :

```
cntlm.exe -v -a NTLMv2 -c cntlm.ini
```

Edit your maven **$MAVEN_HOME\conf\settings.xml**, and use proxies block:

```
<proxies>
   <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>localhost</host>
      <port>3128</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>localhost|127.0.0.1</nonProxyHosts>
   </proxy>
</proxies>
```

Now run maven with `-s` option:

```
mvn -s $MAVEN_HOME\conf\settings.xml <goal>
```

Comment: It seems like the m2eclipse ignores the proxy configuration of the user's settings.xml as adding the same proxy configuration to the global settings.xml resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I too stumble upon this issue, spent a lot of time to search for a solution to NTLM error. NTLM issue does not get away even if we prefix user name with domain name just in proxy tag, we also need to prefix user ids in server tags like given below...

```
<server>
    <id>isb-libs-dev</id>
    <username><internal.java.corp>\username</username>
    <password>password</password>
</server>
```