# Maven 3 Eclipse Kepler is it necessary to have the environment variable to work for embedded Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have installed the last version of kepler the one has the maven embedded in it 
when I tried many times to create application from any archetype 
 I always got

```
Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:RELEASE from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:RELEASE
Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\onourdean\.m2\repository)
Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\onourdean\.m2\repository)
```

even though:

1. I have deleted the repository folder inside .m2 and its created again by it self
2. I have downloaded an external maven and used it
3. I made the proxy in sittings on both the embedded and the external

any other ideas? My settings.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<pluginGroups>
 </pluginGroups>
 <proxies>
  <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>stsproxy</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>localhost|127.0.0.1</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
 <servers>
 </servers>
 <mirrors>
 </mirrors>
 <profiles>
 </profiles>
</settings>
```

Note That:
i have tried all the soultions in the [Create a Maven project in Eclipse complains "Could not resolve archetype"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506043/create-a-maven-project-in-eclipse-complains-could-not-resolve-archetype) except making a variable for maven due to company restriction so is this variable necessary to run the embedded version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its seems there is a bug in the embedded version even if i use it outside of the proxy just used the external version

then use `wagon-http-lightweight-2.2.jar` as described in 
[Can access maven repository from behind proxy, need help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855339/can-access-maven-repository-from-behind-proxy-need-help)

and its worked

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's still the same with Kepler, but with earlier Eclipse (and M2E) releases this problem usually goes away if you go to `Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Installations` and add your local, external Maven installation, which usually causes Eclipse to pick up the correct `settings.xml` file.

Comment: i did try your solution as mentioned in my question its in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506043/create-a-maven-project-in-eclipse-complains-could-not-resolve-archetype @Nicola Musatti