# Maven NTLM proxy

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I read a number of threads with the same issue, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855339/can-access-maven-repository-from-behind-proxy-need-help#) (and all the threads liked in it), but I'm not able to run Maven with the proxy. I tried all possible configurations and I put the same XML content in the default settings and the user one. I got this error:

> [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one
>   of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to
>   repo.jenkins-ci.org (https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/): Error
>   transferring file: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX
>   path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target from
>   https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
>   with proxyInfo ProxyInfo{host='127.0.0.1', userName='null', port=3128,
>   type='http', nonProxyHosts='null'} -> [Help 1]

The unusual thing this is that the username is reported as `null` even if my XML looks like:

```
<proxies>
    <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>MY_HOST</host>
      <port>MY_PORT</port>
      <username>MY_DOMAIN\USERNAME</username>
   </proxy>
</proxies>
```

The password is missing, but obviously I also tried with it.

Comment: Looks like an HTTPS problem, but you specified as protocol http?

Comment: I also tried it. It does not work too.

Comment: For me it worked by specifying only   <proxies>

  <proxy>
      <id>ID</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>127.0.0.1</host>
      <port>13128</port>
    </proxy>
 </proxies> and in NTLM I added the user/ pw.

Comment: Is your the cntlm daemon running? Did you put the `wagon-http-lightweight-2.2.jar` into `M2_HOME\lib\ext`?

Comment: For what do you need the wagon-http-lightweight-2.2.jar ?

Comment: It was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16659942/7810036) as an alternative solution. I tried it since the others did not work.