# How to configure Maven behind proxy

Tags: maven, proxy, configure

I can´t use Maven in my workplace, I think it's because there is something missing in the proxy settings.

I have tried to fill the settings.xml using the proxy info I have:

```
  <proxies>
<proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <host>xxxxxxxxxxx</host>
  <port>xxxx<port>
</proxy>
```

I think something is happening because the files estructure seems to work, but after several minutes waiting I open the downloaded file and it always shows the following:

https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.error=Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): TransferFailedException

Comment: Talk to your network administrator if the proxy allows MavenCentral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my company proxy is NTLM, so this answer was the right solution for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16659942/7698050

Now I can use Maven thru the Console, but I can't do it thru Eclipse IDE...